# Prevent local branch from pushing to upstream branch in DevOps using VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, branching-and-merging, upstream-branch

I have three branches (in DevOps), ***A***, ***B***, and ***C***. In my case, ***A*** is the main, ***B*** is a development trunkline, and ***C*** is a feature being developed for ***B***.

While working on ***C***, I'd like to be pulling changes from ***B*** when I fetch and pull. However, when I push, I only want to push to ***C***. I want to be forced to create pull requests to merge ***C*** back into ***B***.

After doing some reading, I learned that I could set ***B*** as the upstream of ***C*** like I would be used to seeing with a forked repository on GitHub. I utilized the following command to do so:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/B
```

However, this doesn't just pull from ***B***, it also pushes changes to ***B*** when I use Visual Studio Code's sync changes button:

[image: Screenshot of the sync changes button for reference.]

How do I ensure that a push, only pushes changes to the repository for ***C***, while pulls will pull changes from ***B***?

Comment: I made a small change to verify where the push and pull were going, and it is indeed not separated, nor does it push to ***C*** at all. It pushes and pulls directly to/from ***B***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easier way to keep a git feature branch up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587686/easier-way-to-keep-a-git-feature-branch-up-to-date)

Comment: @Matt I'm hoping that's not the answer here; perhaps there's something VSCode itself can offer to maybe set the target of pull and push separately? I'm still actively researching this, so if I find something outside of aliasing or scripting, I'll be sure to come back and update.

Comment: Maybe this then, [How to set up branches with different pull/push upstreams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638858/how-to-set-up-branches-with-different-pull-push-upstreams).  Although personally, I like to issue explicit commands so it is obvious what you are getting.  I feel like merge/rebase steps are a pretty fundamental part of git.

Comment: This is a VSCode "feature" so presumably tag [tag:git] doesn't apply. You *used* [tag:git], though, so: In command-line Git, `git config push.default` can be used to control how `git push` behaves when the upstream of `C` is set to `origin/B`.

Comment: @torek I'm not necessarily focused on the button itself, I just included it to give a better picture of what I'm doing on my side. VS Community behaves the same, so I assumed I might need some additional git commands to get it set up properly.

Comment: I don't think VSCode or VSCommunity obeys the `push.default` settings, but I don't actually *use* either of those. You can create a test repo and do some experiments. See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) under `push.default` for what the settings are.