# Issue with Git rebase invalid upstream 'develop'

Tags: git

I have a situation whereby I created a feature branch from develop 3 months ago, and since that time other colleagues have been working on other feature branches which got released into develop. I now want to integrate my changes into develop as well without breaking thier code and without my code breaking.

I researched this and found the answer here [Easier way to keep a git feature branch up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587686/easier-way-to-keep-a-git-feature-branch-up-to-date). Followed the steps below.

```
git checkout feature/foo
git pull --all
git rebase develop
```

I get the error.
fatal: invalid upstream 'develop'

On reading the page further, I tried the below

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout feature/xxxx
git merge develop 
git push
```

My question is this, after following the link specified earlier, why did I get the error. fatal: invalid upstream 'develop'. I am asking this in cases where I want to use the rebase option.

Comment: So after all the talk, the question is merely how to resolve a merge conflict? See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/ for basic instructions

Comment: Hugely disappointed I got marked down for the questions, I should have made it clear but there are 2 questions there, the first being why I got the error . fatal: invalid upstream 'develop', especially after the answer was voted several times as the correct answer and I leveraged it, is there something I am missing here ?

Comment: There are tutorials on how to complete merges with merge conflicts, have you tried following some of them? Here's one of them - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts

Comment: the merge conflicts i can resolve, I am keen to understand `fatal: invalid upstream 'develop'`. Can someone please upvote my question as I have edited it to make my question clearer.

Comment: As for why `develop` was invalid before, the reason was most likely that you had never checked out `develop` locally, so git didn't know which branch you were talking about. After fetching from the remote, you would have `origin/develop`, assuming your remote was named `origin`, and you could've rebased on top of that with the same effect. You checking out `develop` created the local tracking branch, and then it succeeded.

Comment: Note that `upstream` in that context does not mean "in the remote repository", it just means "the branch you want to rebase on".

Comment: No matter how you look at it there are too many threads here. You make a false assertion about how to behave towards a merge conflict, and you mention a Git error message you don't understand. Please decide what the question is and ask it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I now know what I had the issue in the first place. The original question has now been edited to be much clearer. Can someone please upvote my question as it still showing -1.

Comment: Please stop special pleading about votes. Stack Exchange crowd sources evaluation. If you don't like that, you won't enjoy the site.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is in two parts, because one is all background and one is the answer to the question you asked.  You should probably read this part first, even though it's just background.

## Background (Long)

I think that the Q-and-A pair in question here (the linked question plus its accepted answer) are just not very good.  The tricky part here is that Git is both simpler and more complex than people think, and people get wrong ideas into their heads, which takes a lot of work to get rid of and replace with the correct model.

**The *wrong* model that people have in mind is that branches are somehow the thing in Git.  But they're not: they're not the thing, whatever "the thing" may mean.**  The problems are that "branches"—[whatever we may mean when we use that word loosely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)—are ambiguous, and when we mean "some subset of commits in a Git repository", they're simply a *consequence*.  That is, *these* branches are like the fact that you have to breathe hard after sprinting.  You don't sprint so that you'll have to breathe hard: you sprint to win a race, or to get exercise, or something along those lines.  The breathing-hard part happens, but it wasn't the *goal*.

Similarly, branches (whatever we might mean by that) happen in Git because of the thing we—and Git—really *do* care about.  "The thing", in this case, is the commit.  **Git is all about commits.  Commits are the *raison d'être* for Git.**  As such, it's crucial to understand the following:

- **A Git repository is a collection of commits.**  In fact, a repository is, at its heart, two databases.  Both are simple [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  One holds Git's internal objects, including the commits (which are the objects we humans will generally care about here), and the other holds names—branch names, tag names, and other names.
- **Commits are numbered.**  Every internal Git object gets a number; commits in particular get a *globally unique* number, which we call a hash ID, or sometimes a Git *OID* (Object ID).  In the past, Git called these *SHA-1 hash IDs* (because the current OIDs are in fact SHA-1 hashes), but Git is moving to SHA-2 [due to SHA-1 having been effectively broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452).
- **Each commit in turn stores two collections.**  We'll get back to this in a moment.

The fact that each commit has a *totally unique* number means that any two Git repositories, on contact with each other, can tell whether they contain the *same* commits just by looking at the numbers.  Your Git software, working with your Git repository, can reach out to other Git software working with another Git repository: you might call this other Git `origin` for instance.  Your Git thus calls up the Git at `origin` and has them list out (some of) *their* commit hash IDs.  If your Git has the *same IDs*, you and they have the *same commits* and you're in sync.  If not, one of you has some commits that the other doesn't, and/or vice versa.  Git is generally quite greedy for commits, so at this point one Git—the one with extra commits—will *give commits to* the other Git, that the other database lacks.  The receiving Git will add those commits to its collection, which will add them to its collection, rather [Borg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg)-like.  ("We will add your biological and technological distinctiveness to our own.")

The numbering system has a few consequences.  One is that because the numbers are cryptographic digests, they're quite random-looking, and inhospitable to humans.  Nobody can remember all the hash IDs.  Fortunately we don't *have* to do that: the computer can do that, and the computer is good at that.  The other is that because the commit's hash ID *is* a cryptographic checksum of the commit's *content*, **no part of any commit can ever be changed.**

## The simple part of Git

Every Git commit has two parts:

- Each commit stores a *full snapshot of every file*.  The files inside a commit are stored in a special, read-only, compressed and—important for various reasons—*de-duplicated* format.  Because all parts of every commit are read-only, it's safe for any commit to *share* any of its file content with any other commit (or even other parts of the same commit).  So no matter what you do with commits—e.g., add a million identical ones—you won't bloat up the repository with duplicated files, *even though* every commit stores every file in a *logical* sense.

  This snapshot aspect of a commit means that it's easy to get every version of the stuff you've ever committed: just find the right hash ID of that commit and there are all your files, exactly as they were at the time you committed them.  So everything is saved for all time, or at least, for as long as you can find the commits' hash IDs.
- Separately from the snapshot, each commit stores *metadata:* information such as who made the commit—name and email address—and when, or *why* they made the commit (their log message: the meaningfulness of this depends on the human, so [not every commit message has a good "why" in it](https://xkcd.com/1296/)).

Now we get to the sneaky tricks in Git.  These are not complicated—not yet anyway—but they're the first key to understanding branching.  **In the metadata for any commit, Git stores a list of previous or *parent* commit hash IDs.**  This list is *usually* exactly one entry long, giving each commit a single parent hash ID.  This kind of commit is an ordinary commit, the kind you make every day, and when we lay them out next to each other in the order you make them, with the latest at the right:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

we get a simple backwards-looking chain.  Here `H` stands in for the real hash ID of the *latest* commit you just made.  It has a snapshot and metadata, and in its metadata, commit `H` stores the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Because Git has a simple key-value store, in which it can look up `G`'s hash ID and obtain commit `G`, Git can actually work with both commit `H` *and* commit `G` "at the same time", as it were.  We just have to give Git the hash ID of commit `H`.

Commit `G`, though, is an ordinary commit: it has a snapshot and metadata, and in its metadata, commit `G` stores the raw hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  So Git can look up the actual commit itself, using just the hash ID of `G` to find `G`'s metadata to find `F`'s hash ID.  So now Git has the `G`-and-`F` pair.

In other words, starting from `H`, Git was able to move back one to `G`, and from there, Git was able to move back one step again to `F`.  Commit `F` is of course also an ordinary commit, with one parent, so Git can now move back one more step.  Git can repeat this forever, or at least, until it gets back to the *very first commit*.  This first commit *can't* point backwards, so it just doesn't:

```
A <-B ... <-G <-H
```

and if we have Git start at `H` and work backwards one hop at a time, Git eventually reaches commit `A` and stops there.

**This is the history in the repository.**  The commits contain the snapshots; every commit stores every file (with de-duplication); and by moving backwards, one commit at a time, Git finds every commit in this simple linear chain.  There's one big hitch though: we have to give Git the hash ID of commit `H`.  How do we find that?

#### Branch and other names

This is where *branch names* enter the picture.  In Git, a branch name—or any other name, for that matter—just contains *one* hash ID.  Assuming that's a commit hash ID,<sup>1</sup> that gives us—or Git—a *last commit* to start from.  From there, Git can work backwards.  Since commits point backwards to their parents, and that's the history in the repository, this is how Git *finds* history.

Note that if we have more than one branch name, we can have more than one "last commit".  To illustrate that, suppose we have a chain of commits that ends at commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

We now create two more branch names, such as `br1` and `br2`, both of which *also point to `H` at the moment:*

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, main
```

All the commits are on *all three branches* at this point.  But as we make *new* commits, Git will move one (and only one) branch name "forward" while we do that.  If we start with `br1` and make a new commit `I`, it will point back to existing commit `H` and drag the name `br1` forward:

```
          I   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

When we make a second new commit we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

The name `br1` points to `J`; `J` points backwards to `I`; `I` points backwards to `H`; and so on.  So by starting at `br1`, Git will find *all* the commits.  Starting at `br2` or `main`, Git will find only the commits that end at `H`.  We have two branches—or is it three branches?  That depends on what we mean by the word *branch*, doesn't it?

Anyway, suppose we now switch to using the name `br2` and make two more commits.  Now we'll have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

We now seem to have three branches.  We definitely have three branch *names*.  Which branch(es) contain commits up through `H`?  Git's answer is: *all of them*.  In fact, we can safely *delete* the name `main` at this point, if we don't care to find `H` directly:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

**Now we only have two branches.  We still have exactly the same commits though.  The branches don't matter!  It's only the *commits* that matter.**

That doesn't mean that the branch names are *useless*, of course.  We—and Git—use them to find *last* commits.  If we want to find any particular given "last" commit quickly—e.g., if we want to count `H` as a "last" commit, even though it's also an intermediate commit—we'll need a name for it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Non-branch-names can sometimes contain non-commit hash IDs.  This is mainly a feature for making tags more useful.  Branch names must always hold *commit* hash IDs.

---

## The complicated parts of Git

I said above that commits are read-only snapshots with metadata.  This is true: the files inside a commit literally cannot be changed, and furthermore, they are in a format that other (non-Git) programs cannot even *read*.  You literally *can't* do any work with these files!  But we need to get work done, so how do we do that?

Git's answer is: you don't work on, or with, the *committed* files.  Instead, Git *extracts* a commit, into a work area, where you actually do your work.  What this means is that, literally, the files you *work with* in Git, are *not in Git*.  They get copied *out* of Git and you work on and with the copies.

When you go to make a *new* commit, you *still* don't use these files directly.  Instead, Git has stored what amount to copies of these files,<sup>2</sup> ready to go into a new commit.  This extra copy of each file occupies something for which Git has three names: the *index*, the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  All three names refer to this same thing, which I like to describe as your *proposed next commit*.

This explains what `git checkout` or `git switch` is doing.  When we use either of these commands and give it a *branch name*, we're really picking *the commit we'd like to extract*.  For instance, if we have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop, main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and we run:

```
git switch main
```

we are telling Git that we want to start working on / with the files that are in commit `H`.  Git should now:

- erase, from our work area and proposed next commit, the *current* files that are there from a previous checkout;
- install, into our work area and proposed next commit, the files from commit `H`.

To remember *which branch name we're using*, we'll update our drawing like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The special name `HEAD`, in all uppercase, is attached to just *one* branch name.  That's the branch name of the branch we are "on".  So if we *were* on `br1`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop, main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and are now on `main`, Git has swapped out all the commit-`J` files for all the commit-`H` files.

There are some special cases here.  Sometimes Git doesn't have to switch out the files.  Suppose that we *were* on `develop`, which means "commit `H`", when we ran `git switch main` to switch to commit `H`.  We're telling Git to switch *from* `H`, *to* `H`.  That's not really much of a switch, is it?  In this case Git doesn't have to change out *any* files, and so it just doesn't bother.

This case becomes important if we *don't* have a `develop` *yet*.  Suppose we're on `main`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and we start changing a bunch of files.  Then we realize: *Hey, wait, I meant to do this work on a new branch.*  We can *create a new branch and switch to it* right now, and as long as the *new* branch *also* means "commit `H`" right now, that switch is totally free, because Git won't need to swap out any files.  We can leave our partially-completed work just partially-completed, creating a new branch name `test2` for instance:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, test2 (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

If and when we eventually make a *new* commit—let's call it `N`—we'll get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \__
          \ `--N   <-- test2 (HEAD)
           \
            K--L   <-- br2
```

New commit `N` will point back to old commit `H` as its parent, because we made commit `N` *from* commit `H`.

This index or staging area—the extra copies of each file that make up the proposed next commit—explain *why* you have to run `git add`.  When you do run `git add`, Git will:

- read the working tree copy;
- compress it into Git's internal format; and
- check for any existing (duplicate) copy.

If there's some existing copy, Git can discard the compressed version it just made, and use the duplicate.  If not, Git will arrange for the new compressed version to go into the repository if and when we finally *do* commit it.<sup>3</sup>

Although this *is* a bit complicated, the parts to memorize aren't that bad:

- **You don't work on committed files.**  You work on *copies* of them.  Git extracts the copies from some existing commit.
- **The files you *do* work on are not in Git.**  They're *copies*.
- **Until you run `git add` on them, Git doesn't even care if files have been updated.**  You should run `git status` often enough to see which files you haven't yet `git add`ed.
- **The `git add` step means *make the index / staging copy match the working tree copy*.**  That is, it updates your *proposed next commit*.
- **When you run `git commit`, Git makes the new commit's snapshot from the proposed next commit.**  This is why you have to `git add`: to update the proposed next commit, so that `git commit` will commit *that*.

This also leads to a proper understanding of `git status`—but we'll come back to that in a moment.

---

<sup>2</sup>The "copies" in Git's index or staging area are already de-duplicated, and remain that way at all times, so unless you've altered a file and run `git add`, these copies take no space.  Technically, what's in the index is really just the file's name, mode, hash ID, and cache data, plus a slot number used during merging; we won't cover this at all.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, Git adds a new blob object immediately.  If we end up not committing it after all, Git will *eventually* clean it up, providing we don't wind up doing another `git add` and `git commit` that *does* eventually commit it.  So if you have a very big file—say, a few dozen terabytes or petabytes—you probably don't want to `git add` it unless and until it's really necessary.  For small files, though, it usually doesn't matter.

---

#### Snapshots vs diffs

I keep coming back to the concept of *snapshots*, because commits *are* snapshots (plus metadata).  But if we look at a commit with, say, `git show` or `git log -p`, we don't *see* a snapshot.  Instead, we *see* a *diff:*

```
$ git show | head -25 | sed 's/@/ /'
commit f01e51a7cfd75131b7266131b1f7540ce0a8e5c1
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 21 14:18:51 2022 -0700

    The thirteenth batch
    
    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>

diff --git a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt
index d67727baa1..f1449eb926 100644
--- a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt
+++ b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt
 @ -74,6 +74,10 @@ UI, Workflows & Features
    refs involved, takes long time renaming them.  The command has been
    taught to show progress bar while making the user wait.
 
+ * Bundle file format gets extended to allow a partial bundle,
+   filtered by similar criteria you would give when making a
+   partial/lazy clone.
+
 
 Performance, Internal Implementation, Development Support etc.
 
 @ -132,6 +136,12 @@ Performance, Internal Implementation, Development Support etc.
```

The things with the `@`s in them are *diff hunks*, and before this we get a *diff header:*

```
diff --git a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt
index d67727baa1..f1449eb926 100644
--- a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt
+++ b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt
```

What Git has done is to take commit `f01e51a7cfd75131b7266131b1f7540ce0a8e5c1`, use its metadata to find its parent `bc3838b310b32081d48393ba0dcf26e4735c6d19`, and extracted the file `Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt` from *both commits*.  On the "left" (as `a/`), Git puts the earlier version of the file; on the "right" (as `b/`), Git puts the later version of the file.  Then Git plays a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).  The first *difference* Git saw was that Junio added four lines around line 77.  The diff shows the added lines, plus a bit of context, then moves on the next *change* that Git found, which is to add more lines around line 135 (in the old version) or 139 (in the new one).

In other words, Git *uses the metadata in the commit to find the (single) parent*.  This gives us two *snapshots*, which Git can compare.  But in fact, Git can make a diff from *any* two snapshots, not just ones that are right next to each other:

```
...--E--F--G--H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

Here `git show` will compare `G` and `H`, as those are the two adjacent commits, but we can run:

```
git diff <hash-of-E> HEAD
```

and have Git compare the snapshots in `E` and `H` directly, and show *that* as a diff.  This all works because *every* commit *holds* a full snapshot, and Git can easily compare *any two snapshots*.  In fact, due to the internal de-duplication, Git can compare two snapshots very quickly as long as most of the files are duplicates: it only has to look at those files that *aren't* duplicates.  So overall, this is quite easy for Git.

#### Merging

This all leads us to `git merge`, which is where Git gets much of its real power.  Let's go back to this setup again:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

This tells us that we're "on" branch `br1`–that is, we did a `git checkout br1` or a `git switch br1`—and that we're using the files from commit `J`.  Let's also say that we haven't touched any of these files (so that the index and working tree copies all match the commit-`J` copies).  We now run:

```
git merge br2
```

Our goal here is to *combine changes*.  That is, we want to take any *work we, or someone else, did* on our `br1` branch, and any work we or anyone else did on the `br2` branch too, and *combine* the work.

We just saw that Git doesn't *store* changes.  But we also saw that Git can easily compare any *two* commits.  How will we get Git to *combine changes?*  We have to do some diff-ing.

We could compare the snapshot in `J` to the one in `L`, but that doesn't really get us what we want.  The trick here is to use the metadata a little differently.  Commit `J` has parent `I`, and commit `I` has parent `H`, which has parent `G`, and so on, backwards.  Meanwhile commit `L` has parent `K`, which has parent `H`, and that goes back to `G`, and so on.  **Some of these parents are shared.**  In fact, as soon as we get back to `H`, *every* parent from there backwards is shared.  That means commit `H`, which is on both branches, is the *best* shared parent.  Git calls this "best" shared parent the *merge base*.<sup>4</sup>

By using this best common ancestor, or merge base, Git can run *two* `git diff`s:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

These two diffs apply to the *same snapshot*—the one in commit `H`—and *now* Git can *combine the diffs*.  As long as we touched files they didn't and they touched files we didn't, that's easy.  When we and they touched the *same* files, Git's rules here are simple: if we didn't touch the same *lines*, and our changes don't butt up against each other, Git takes *both* changes.  If we *did* touch the same lines, Git requires that we make the *same change* to those same lines, and then Git takes *one* of those changes.  If our changes can't be combined, Git calls that a *merge conflict*.

**This is what merge conflicts are about.**  Git has picked some *merge base* commit, and has diff-ed its snapshot against two other commits' snapshots.  Git is now trying to *combine changes*.  Git has encountered a case where its simple, line-based, text-oriented rules don't have a simple answer for how to combine these, so Git says "conflict".

Note: Git can also detect files that were all-new, or removed entirely, or renamed.  This produces a different kind of merge conflict—some call it a *tree* conflict; I call it a *high level* conflict—that doesn't involve particular lines *within* a file, but rather some entire thing to do with that file.  For instance, suppose we added some functions to `subroutines.py` and they *deleted* `subroutines.py` entirely.  Git has no idea how to combine "add these lines" with "delete this file", so it will call that a *modify/delete conflict*.

In all these conflict cases, Git dumps the job of *resolving* the conflict onto the human, who presumably understands the file's contents.  The human doesn't just apply simple text-substitution rules.  The human knows whether changing `red ball` to `blue ball` on one side of the merge, and `red ball` to `red cube` on the other side, should result in `blue cube`, or maybe in `green pyramid` or whatever.

But if there *isn't* a conflict—if the merge goes smoothly—Git will take the *combined changes*, whatever those wind up being, and apply them to the *base snapshot*.  That is, given:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Git combines our `H`-vs-`J` changes with their `H`-vs-`L` changes and applies *both* changes to `H`.  That keeps our work and adds theirs, or keeps their work and adds ours, however you'd like to look at it.  Then Git makes a new *commit* from this result, and this new commit is special in exactly one way:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Commit `M` is a *merge commit*.  It has a snapshot, just like any commit.  It has metadata, just like any commit.  What's special about it is that instead of *one* parent, it has *two*.  Commit `M` points back to existing commit `J`, in the way a new commit does.  But commit `M` *also* points back to *merged* commit `L`.

This—the two parents—is what makes commit `M` a *merge commit*.  Of course the snapshot, in this case, is the result of merging *changes* as well, but that's not what makes `M` a *merge commit*.  It's the *two parents* that make `M` a merge commit.

Note that, as usual, Git has updated the *current branch name* to point to the new commit.  So `br1` now means "commit `M`", not "commit `J`".  No commits have changed—no commits can *ever* change—but the *branch name* has moved as usual.

What's unusual is that because `M` points back to `L` as well as to `J`, we *may* no longer care about *finding* commit `L` with a branch name.  It's now safe to delete the *name* `br2`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

because we can still find all the *commits* by starting at `M` and working backwards.  It's trickier now, because when we step back once from `M`, we have to visit *both* commits `J` *and* `L`.  Then we have to visit *both* `I` *and* `K`, and then we visit `H` once, and then step back to `G`, and so on.  **Git knows how to do this, but it *is* tricky, and this is one of the harder things to understand in Git.**  Peculiarly, the split—where the two branches fork off from `H` initially—is actually *easier*, and the merge at `M`, where the two branches come together, is hard.  That's because Git works backwards, and when we work backwards, it's the merges that split, and the splits that merge, as it were.  But remember that commits hold *snapshots and metadata* and you'll be fine: the merge holds a *snapshot*.  Preparing the snapshot might have been hard, and figuring out *why* it's *that* snapshot, despite what's in the parent commits `J` and `L` might be hard, but it's still just a snapshot.

**Do note, though,** that the "show a commit as a patch" trick that `git log -p` uses for ordinary commits stops working here.  When we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

Git will compare the `G` and `H` snapshots to show a diff, but when we have:

```
...--J
      \
       M   <-- branch (HEAD)
      /
...--L
```

which snapshot should Git compare to the snapshot in `M`?  **The answer `git log` uses by default is *this is too hard, so I won't bother showing anything at all*.**  That's not a very good answer, but be aware of it.  (There is no single *right* answer to the dilemma, but it might be nice if `git log -p` inserted *something* to indicate it didn't bother to do any work here.)

---

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the merge base of two commits is found using the [Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm on the DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) formed by the commits.  Sometimes there's more than one LCA, and this complicates merging, but we'll ignore this case entirely here.

Comment: "Git is generally quite greedy for commits, so at this point one Git—the one with extra commits—will give commits to the other Git, that the other database lacks. " What happens if one git has commits A and B, while the other has C and D ? Neither one has extra commits, indeed both have completely different commits. Essentially, we have apples and oranges.

Comment: Also, when you login/open the CLI to git, do you *have* to be on some branch or the other? Or can where you find yourself to be in an undefined/neutral state? From this state, you can *then* go to a branch of your liking? At any point in time subsequently, can you find yourself in such a neutral/undefined nonbranch state? Or are you always on some branch or the other?

Comment: "Suppose we're on main and we start changing a bunch of files". This would mean that the working tree has changed and does not match the index prior to git add. " I meant to do this work on a new branch. We can create a new branch and switch to it right now, and as long as the new branch also means "commit H" right now, that switch is totally free," This isn't clear. If we create a new branch *now* (prior to git add which would make working tree = index) what happens to the current working tree and index?

Comment: You do answer my above question when you say "Git won't need to swap out any files. We can leave our partially-completed work just partially-completed, creating a new branch name test2 for instance:"
Is this true whether or not the working tree has diverged from the index? I suppose this is where stashing comes into play ?

Comment: @Tryer: Your Git will grab C&D from the other Git (`git fetch`), or give A&B to the other Git (`git push`). The transfer direction is always one-way. After getting new commits, whichever Git has them needs to set up some name(s) by which to *find* them or they're vulnerable to `git gc` (after fetch) or being dropped due to the quarantine thing Git uses (after push). (GitHub added the idea of the quarantine area: incoming commits go here, rather than into the repository database proper, until the push is accepted, and only then get migrated. This saves them disk space if the push is rejected.)

Comment: Note that if the two sub-graphs (A<-B and C<-D) are not connected at all, that's not a big deal: you just have two independent sub-graphs in your repo. Given, say, names `main` and `origin/foo` pointing to B and D respectively, `git merge origin/foo` will complain that the histories are unrelated (since Git 2.9).

Comment: You don't really "log in" to Git: a Git repo just kind of sits there quietly until some Git command is run, at which point Git opens stuff from `.git` and figures out the state. There *is* a "no current branch at all" state: here `HEAD` contains a raw commit hash ID. There is also a "no current commit, but you're on a non-existent branch" state: here `HEAD` contains the name of a branch that doesn't exist. In any case whatever is in Git's index is in Git's index. If `.git/index` does not *exist*, the index is effectively empty and all files are therefore untracked.

Comment: Basically, think of everything in terms of "state": a Git command starts up and checks to see what state things are in. Ah, there's a `HEAD`, we read it, it contains a branch name, we're on that branch. Does that branch exist? If so, we're on that commit, otherwise we're on an "orphan" or "unborn" branch. Meanwhile, does `.git/index` exist? If so, read it: that's what's in the index. Does the working tree exist? If so, read it: that's what's in the working tree.

Comment: As for stashing: all `git stash` does is make two (default) or three (`-a`, `-u`) commits. Aside from the fancy new partial stash features that went in with `git stash push` taking over from `git stash save`, one of the two commits contains whatever was in the index at that time, and the other contains the result of `git add -u` and committing. (Git makes extra, temporary index files as needed for some of these steps in case it's important to preserve the existing index. A temporary index can be filled in by reading the HEAD commit or by copying the existing index.)

Comment: The third commit, if it exists, holds the extra files (untracked files, perhaps including ignored untracked files): to add these Git uses an extra (initially empty) index and adds the untracked files to that (bypassing .gitignore if needed) and writes that out with `git write-tree`, which is the internal command that turns the index into a tree object, and then uses `git commit-tree` to turn the tree into the third commit. Then Git runs `git clean` to remove the untracked files in the third commit. Whether or not you make the third commit, Git uses `git reset --hard` to reset the work-tree.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume a lot of background, so see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71624154/1256452) first.

> I researched this and found the answer here [Easier way to keep a git feature branch up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587686/easier-way-to-keep-a-git-feature-branch-up-to-date). Followed the steps below.
>
> ```
> git checkout feature/foo
> git pull --all
> git rebase develop
> ```

Let's assume here that `feature/foo` is an existing branch name in your repository.  The reason to assume it is this:

- The `git checkout` command has some extra features.  These used to be always-on, but you can now turn off the "guess" mode with `--no-guess`.
- If you *don't* turn off `--no-guess`, `git checkout` will sometimes *create a new branch name* (and then do the checkout).

Let's pause now and look at what happens when you connect two Git repositories to each other, e.g., using the name `origin`.  I mentioned earlier that when two Git repositories meet, one of those two repositories generally winds up giving the other Git software some or all of any *new-to-it* commits.  They use the raw hash IDs, and their branch names—each of the two Git repositories has *its own* branch names; it's only the commits and their hash IDs that are literally shared—to accomplish this.

When you use `git pull`, you're telling your Git to run two Git commands:

1. `git fetch`;
2. a second Git command that you can configure.

We'll get to the second command after talking about `git fetch`.  The fetch command has your Git reach out to some other Git repository.  To do that, your Git needs a URL.  Your Git has *saved* a URL under the name `origin`, and your `git fetch` is using the name `origin` to retrieve the saved URL, so your Git reaches out to whatever URL that is.  Some other Git software answers the "Internet phone call" your Git makes *to* that URL.  That Git software reads *their* Git repository, and announces to your Git all of their branch names and all the commit hash IDs that go with those names.

Your Git now looks at those hash IDs first.  If you already have the hash ID, you already have their commit.  But if not, you're missing some commit(s): your Git software will now ask their Git *please send that commit and tell me about its parent(s)*.  Their Git software will send over the parent hash IDs; your Git will check to see if you have those, and if not, request those too, and so on.  In the end, then, you'll get *all the new commits they have:* any commits *they* have, that you didn't, well, now you do have them.  They're all safely tucked away in your own Git repository now.

Once you have all of their commits, your Git now saves all of their *branch names*.  But your Git doesn't use their branch names as your *branch* names.  Instead, your Git takes their names—`master` or `main`, `develop`, `feature/foo`, whatever names they have—and sticks `origin/` in front.  Why `origin/`?  Because you called up their Git using the *name* `origin`.  That name, `origin`, provided the prefix for these renamed things.

The renamed things are not exactly *branch* names.  They *correspond to* the other Git's branch names.  Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, but since they're not *branch* names, I like to simplify this to just *remote-tracking names*.

If we draw the commits in your repository the way I like to, we may end up with something like this, *before* you run `git pull` which runs `git fetch`:

```
          K--L   <-- feature/foo (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

The reason you have a `main` is that your Git created one right after you ran `git clone`.  The reason you have a `feature/foo` is that *you* created this one.  The reason you have an `origin/main` and an `origin/develop` is that they had a `main` and a `develop` at the time you ran `git clone`.  Your Git got all of their *commits*, but didn't create *branch names* for their branches: your Git made *remote-tracking names* instead.

Let's assume now that they've made a couple of new commits on *their* `develop`.  You run `git fetch` (via `git pull`), so your Git (your software on your repo) calls up their Git (their software on their repo) and their Git lists out their `develop` as meaning commit `O`.  You don't have `O` so your Git asks their Git to send `O`; they mention that `O`'s parent is `N`, and you don't have `N` so your Git asks them to send that too; they say that `N`'s parent is `J`, which you *do* have, so that finishes off the set of commits they need to send.

They send those commits to you, and your Git adds them to its distinctiveness, Borg-like:

```
          K--L   <-- feature/foo (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
              \
               N--O
```

Having done all that, your Git now updates your `origin/develop` to point to commit `O`, since their `develop` now points to commit `O`:

```
          K--L   <-- feature/foo (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J--N--O   <-- origin/develop
```

Your `git fetch` step is now complete.  Your Git disconnects from their Git—you don't need the Internet any more, at this point.

Your Git goes on to do the second command that `git pull` runs.  The *default* second command here is `git merge`.  Here's where things get tricky.

Remember that we ran `git merge br2` in our earlier example.  We *have to tell `git merge` which commit to merge*.  We usually use a branch name for that, or—in this case—maybe a remote-tracking name.  But they at least *two* branch names, `main` and `develop`, which turned into your `origin/main` and `origin/develop`.

What `git pull` does here is to use an *upstream*.  Each branch name in your repository—`main` and `feature/foo`—can have *one upstream* set.  The upstream of a branch is something you would set with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to
```

**You do not have to have an upstream set** but if you do not have one set, `git pull` will just complain.  My guess here is that, at some point in the past, you ran:

```
git push -u origin feature/foo
```

which sent your commits `K-L` to the other Git over at `origin`, so that they have them.  This then also asked them to *create*, in *their* repository, the name `feature/foo`.  Note that there's no prefix here: this is an actual *branch* name.

When you do all this, they get the new commits you have that they don't—commits `K` and `L`—and then they do create their branch `feature/foo`.  That means your Git knows to create `origin/feature/foo` in *your* repository, so that the picture really looks like this now:

```
          K--L   <-- feature/foo (HEAD), origin/feature/foo
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J--N--O   <-- origin/develop
```

The `-u` flag to `git push` tells `git push` to run `git branch --set-upstream-to` *for you* after the `git push` succeeds.  The name that `git push` uses, when it does this, is `origin/feature/foo`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/foo feature/foo
```

which means that the upstream of your `feature/foo` is `origin/feature/foo`.

So, your `git pull` obtained their new commits on their `develop` and updated your `origin/develop`.  It then updated—or would have updated—your `origin/main` and `origin/feature/foo`, except that there was nothing to do here, because those names already selected the right commit.

Then, your Git ran the equivalent of:

```
git merge origin/feature/foo
```

to complete your `git pull`.  But that said to merge commit `L` with commit `L`, which does nothing at all.  So Git doesn't bother trying to merge: it just says `Already up to date.`

#### Side note: `--all`

Git takes that `--all` flag in `git pull --all` and hands it to `git fetch`.  Here, it means *all remotes*.  That's all `--all` means: *all remotes*.  Most people have just one remote, named `origin`.  If you have more than one, this makes your `git pull` fetch from all of them.  If you just have the one remote, the `--all` flag does absolutely nothing.  In any case, it has no effect on the *second* command that `git pull` runs.  So you never need `--all` here, and probably should never use it: it does nothing you would care about.

#### `git rebase`

The rebase command is complicated, and I won't go into details here (look for other SO answers), but at its heart, it means:

- I have some commits.
- I like most of the things about these commits, but there's something I *don't* like about them.
- I know no commit can ever be changed.  But let me *copy* the commits that I do have, and before I `git commit` each *copied* commit, let me *change something* first.

Since a commit is a snapshot plus metadata, there are only two things you can change: the snapshot, or the metadata, or in some cases both.  The goal of a rebase is therefore to take your existing commits, that are "mostly OK", and make new and improved commits that are somehow better.

To do this, Git needs two pieces of information:

- What commits should be copied?
- Where should the copies go?

When you run `git rebase develop`, Git gets—or tries to get—both answers from that one name, `develop`.  That name:

1. must exist;
2. must name a *commit*.

You got an error because `develop`, as a name, did not exist:

> ```
> fatal: invalid upstream 'develop'
> ```

Git isn't very good at its error messages, but in this case, that's what it meant.

When you ran:

> ```
> git checkout develop
> ```

you invoked the `--guess` mode.  You had:

```
          K--L   <-- feature/foo (HEAD), origin/feature/foo
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J--N--O   <-- origin/develop
```

Note that there is no `develop` here.  Your Git will, at this point, be almost ready to give you an error message (another of Git's low-quality ones that doesn't mention the real problem), but since you *didn't* use `--no-guess`, `git checkout` takes one last stab at solving the lack of name `develop`.  It looks through your *remote-tracking names* and finds that `origin/develop` *does* exist.  It changes your:

```
git checkout develop
```

command into:

```
git checkout -b develop --track origin/develop
```

which tells Git:

1. create name `develop` pointing to the same commit as `origin/develop`;
2. check out that branch name, having just created it;
3. set the upstream for `develop` to `origin/develop`

That is, this `--guess` mode is a three-in-one command.  Its final result is this:

```
          K--L   <-- feature/foo, origin/feature/foo
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J--N--O   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

Your next command:

> ```
> git pull
> ```

can now run: it means:

- `git fetch` (from origin), which probably didn't get anything new this time since your earlier `git fetch` was pretty recent;
- `git merge origin/develop`, which probably did not have anything to do and would say `Already up to date`.

Your subsequent `git merge` would do a real merge, given the drawings I made, and that could well get merge conflicts.  You probably *wanted* to rebase instead, but that gets particularly tricky due to the commit-copying steps.

## Bottom line

It's kind of a shame that *using* Git gets so difficult.  Parts of Git really are very simple, and once you get past the trickier ones—the whole idea of working tree and index/staging-area, for instance, or how merge works—the rest starts getting simpler again.  Rebase is really just repeated `git cherry-pick`, and each cherry-pick is a kind of merge (using a forced merge base).  Some `git merge` commands do a *fast-forward* operation instead of a merge, but fast-forwarding is really just a branch-label-movement trick and is pretty simple itself.

Unfortunately, there's a huge amount of bad assumptions—such as that `git pull` is for beginners who have not yet learned all the intricacies of fetching and merging—and there is that first lump of "stuff" to get past.

Once you do get past it, though, you'll realize that "commits are snapshots plus metadata" really cuts through a lot of stuff.